# Touchpad not working on ASUS x550

Tags: release-freya, touchpad

i really like freya. but i have tried everything and it does not recognize the synaptic touchpad. Help, please?

Comment: Would you mind to add a list of "everything" you tried? It's easier to help you if we know *what* did not work :)

Comment: at first i thought it must be disabled from bios, it wasn't. i tried getting the id and enable it from the terminal, it din not have an id. i also tried sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps did nothing.

Comment: i tried reinstalling sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics. still nothing. updated kernels, nothing

Answer (score 6):

Answered already in the previous answer's comments.
Restating here for the upcoming users, so it would be easy to follow.

#### Solution:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install focaltech-dkms
sudo modprobe -r psmouse 
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

#### Note: This works on all debian based distros (Ubuntu, elementary OS and so on)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue on Asus X555U. If i run xinput list i don't even see any touchpad... it just list Virtual core XTEST pointer. Does this solution will work for me even if i don't see FocalTech emulation mode?

Answer (score 2):

X55 series uses elantech touchpad. Upgrade to kernel 4.0 or above it will solve the problem.

Comment: updating kernel did not work for me :( but thank you

Comment: can you post the result of xinput list

Comment: Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 FocalTech FocalTech Touchpad in mouse emulation mode id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]

Comment: Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]

Comment: ↳ USB Camera                                id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1  id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]

Comment: now i am using kubuntu with a fix i found on a forum. i am searching for the fix and i will post it as soon as i find it

Comment: if you know a fix for freya i would like to switch back

Comment: Do this 

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install focaltech-dkms

Comment: If you have a Focaltech touchpad, then do this.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install focaltech-dkms

The touchpad will work after reboot. That's it


sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse


or reboot

Comment: that is the fix i used for kubuntu, it will work for freya as well? (i am sorry if i ask noob questions but this is my first linux and i prefer freya :)) )

Comment: yup that's what you need to do. it doesn't matter which distro of ubuntu you use. Hardware errors are same everywhere and the fix is same for each one of them.

Comment: thank you very much, i will reinstall freya and try the fix. thanks again!

Comment: Welcome, Hope you enjoy freya :).

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issues.so i tried different kernel and works only fine in 4.2.0-36-lowlatency . When i tried  linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic the touch pad was not stable and had some random issues with clicks