# Two-finger Scroll is not working for my touchpad of ASUS X200MA

Tags: touchpad

I installed elementary OS Freya 0.3.2 on my ASUS X200MA, run all the updates. I wanted to activate two-finger scroll, ticked the option in the mouse and trackpad system settings. But it doesn't work. I re-entered the system settings, and it doesn't save the option that I'd ticked.

Is it a kernel problem, or a problem derived from its 14.04 Ubuntu base?
Because the two finger-scroll is working well in, let's say, Ubuntu 15.10 and all its derivatives.

Comment: Try http://askubuntu.com/a/489239/480305

Answer (score 2):

If you use synaptics driver you will probably have the synclient program installed. In terminal have a look at your current touchpad settings:

`$ synclient -l | sort`
(Of course it will show the settings without the "sort" - but it is much easier to find settings when they are listed in alphabetically order)

You will get a list with many settings. We are interested in the option "VertTwoFingerScroll". If the output is "VertTwoFingerScroll = 0" the option is disabled. To enable try

`$ synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I followed your instruction and found out that I didn't have my synaptics driver installed. Then I stumbled upon this http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/821/touchpad-not-working-on-asus-x550 , and now my touchpad works like a charm. It's said that my laptop use elantech driver, and this problem is solved out of the box in 4.x kernel. So it's considered solved, then.

Answer (score 0):

go to system settings and enable multi touch along with two finger scrolling . then it should work fine. i am using asus ux305