# Touchpad two finger scrolling won't turn on

Tags: mouse, touchpad

Every time i turn on the two finger scrolling in the system settings, it wont turn on and when i close the system settings the two finger scrolling setting unchecks itself.

Everything worked fine in Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here: [Two-finger Scroll is not working for my touchpad of ASUS X200MA](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4270/two-finger-scroll-is-not-working-for-my-touchpad-of-asus-x200ma?rq=1)

Maybe you have better luck in terminal...