# Two Finger Scrolling doesn't work on elementaryOS Hera on VMWare Player

Tags: release-hera, touchpad

Two finger scroll doesn't work on elementaryOS 5.1.6 Hera:

- Built on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- Linux 5.4.0-42-generic
- VMware SVGA II Adapter

#### Things I have already tried:

1. [Touchpad not working on ASUS x550](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/942/23558)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install focaltech-dkms
sudo modprobe -r psmouse 
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

2. [Two-finger Scroll is not working for my touchpad of ASUS X200MA](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/4270/23558)
3. Installing `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` left my distro inaccessible after a reboot, keyboard and mouse stopped working.
4. Because of 3. i couldn't try `synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1`

### Touchpad Setting

[image: Touchpad Settings]

### xinput list logs

[image: xinput list logs]

### lspci logs[image: lspci logs]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, and solved it by following this guide for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS which is what Elementary OS Hera is based upon.

https://vitux.com/how-to-activate-two-finger-scrolling-in-ubuntu/

I didn't have to edit the configuration file, but after removing the libinput, and adding the synaptics package and rebooted then two finger scrolling started working. I ran the synclient command, and found that VertTwoFingerScrolling was already set to "1".

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. However, this may work for others. Thanks for your answer @agtigdk