# ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad. Buttons work, cannot swipe

Tags: touchpad

I have installed Elementary OS recently. At some point my touchpad stopped to work. Not completely, but I cannot *move* it, all I can do is click.

I have tried to enable it at settings. Turning on/off on laptop shortcuts. Nothing really worked.

It worked before, but somehow stopped.
Any ideas guys?

Laptop Lenovo Y510P, ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad.

Best, Jacob

Answer (score 1):

If you don't already have these drivers, I would recommend installing them:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms
sudo apt update
sudo apt install focaltech-dkms
sudo modprobe -r psmouse 
sudo
```

modprobe psmouse

If this doesn't help try the following command as root:

```
echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio4/reg_07
```

These worked for me when I had that laptop, but that was about 6 months ago, so not sure if that's still the problem. I just know that Elantech touch-pads don;t seem to like debian based distros.

if neither of these works, you can try install the gcc drivers (I haven't personally tried these though):

```
sudo apt install switchboard-plug-gcc-mouse
```

Some helpful links, for reference:

- [Link 1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2271795)
- [Link 2](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/821/touchpad-not-working-on-asus-x550)

Comment: I believe I have these drivers installed, but just for sure followed commands. And the echo didn't work at all. 
`bash: /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio4/reg_07: No such file or directory`

I have also GCC drivers installed. Maybe that's the reason why?

EDIT: Uninstalled GCC drivers and didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it somehow while struggling with Bumblebee and Primus.

I believe  `sudo apt-get install  xorg-x11-drv-mouse`  might be the answer.