# ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad not working after update

Tags: touchpad, drivers

My ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad stopped working after an update.
Before a few days it worked fine, but now I can't do anything only the buttons are working.
It seems to be the same problem as described here: 
[ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad. Buttons work, cannot swipe](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/5314/etps-2-elantech-touchpad-buttons-work-cannot-swipe)

I tried the solution described there, but installing the `focaltech-dkms` drivers, `modprobe -r psmouse` and `modprobe psmouse` didn't help.
I rebooted and checked if touchpad is activated in the system-settings.

Has anyone a clue where to look further or another solution?

`xinput` gives me the following line:

> `# xinput
>
>   ⎜ ↳  ...
>
>   ⎜ ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad id=15 [slave pointer (2)]`,

so it seems to be recognized.

---

**EDIT:** I also tried the solution below, but there is no `serio4` directory, only `serio0` and `serio1`. Since the change is not permanent apparently, I tried this command (as root, didn't work with sudo):

> `echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/reg_07`
>   It executes without an error, but the touchpad still doesn't work.

`cat /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/reg_07` gives me `0x07` as output. Is this correct? Shouldn't be there a `1` or at least a change?

---

**EDIT.EDIT:** When the screen turns black due power saving options, it gets back to life when I touch the touchpad, but the mouse pointer is still not moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my gosh, I totally forgot that I had to install the `xorg-dev` package for testing purposes. It seems that the `xserver-xorg-input-mtrack` package was removed with this process.
After re-install `xserver-xorg-input-mtrack` and rebooting the notebook everything is back to normal!
Thanks @dave-g for your help. I would say a win-win: touchpad is working again and I have updated my kernel =)

---

**EDIT:** To clarify: Updating the kernel didn't help, but without the correct `xorg`-driver it never could.

---

**EDIT.EDIT:** 'Cause the `xserver-xorg-input-mtrack` didn't work well *(two finger swipe let the pointer jump around)* I had to install `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and reboot to have the best touchpad *(or trackpad?? Seriously I'm confused..)* experience.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug regarding the ETPS/2 touchpad, try the following in a terminal:

sudo su - 
echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio4/reg_07

If it works it will only work til you reboot so you will need to add the line:

echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio4/reg_07

to /etc/rc.local just before 'exit 0' to make it run that command at boot.

Edit....

If serio4 doesn't exist you can find out which one it should be  with

cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -iA 9 touch

Comment: Sry, forgot to mention that I tried that also. I'll edit my question..

Comment: Can you plug a mouse in and use it, if so it confirms it is an issue with the touchpad, if the mouse doesn't work then it could be an issue with x-windows or part of the desktop environment. If its just the track pad you could try updating to the latest kernel as the bug I mentioned is in the older kernel. You can do that by opening a terminal and typing: sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-xenial . You will have to reboot for it to take effect.