# Touchpad scrolling doesn't work on ASUS x540ls

Tags: touchpad

I tried to turn double finger scrolling through settings but it doesn't work. Tried googling for a solution but there isn't an obvious one. Please, help me enable two finger scrolling.

I guess there is a problem with the driver since scrolling worked well on Ubuntu.

Thank you!

PS. I trried the solution from this post - [Touchpad not working on ASUS x550](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/821/touchpad-not-working-on-asus-x550) - but it didn't work.

Comment: I have the same (besides others) problem with my Dell Inspiron 13-7359. I've been looking for some solutions, but nothing worked so far.